# Why there are three attrib.exe in window 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance

What's the `attrib.exe`?

they are used my CPU near to 100%

[image][image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the “Details” (详细信息) tab with the “Command Line” column enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have not indicated the full path of the files, but there should be only
two, and they should not be running unless manually invoked:

```
C:\Windows\System32\attrib.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\attrib.exe
```

Your computer is most likely infected by a virus. See the article
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Comment: Just because multiple *instances* of the process are active doesn’t mean it’s a virus. The description field also translates to “Attribute utility”, which matches the English description of `attrib.exe`.

Comment: @DanielB: If this is the real attrib, then with this usage of the CPU they must each be running over a large portion of the disk. The poster would certainly have known if he had launched 3 such instances of attrib. So if he doesn't know, then this is either a virus, or his kid brother decided to annoy him.

Comment: I second what DanielB says - it *most likely* is a virus, but doesn't have to be. It may as well be some race condition. I saw something similar happening on my win10 laptop post-windows-update, where I killed one of the processess and the other finished and quit on its own.

Comment: @Kitet: I changed "surely" to "most likely" and hope that we have all now reached a consensus.